# Dropbox Paper - Erroneous accent is added on the space that preceeds an accented greek vowel

Tags: mac, firefox, dropbox

On Dropbox Paper, on the latest Firefox (69.0.1), when **typing in greek,** if the first letter of a word is an accented vowel, the preceeding space also gets an accent.

This happens **most** of the times but not always. I have not managed to identify the conditions in which it doesn't happen.

This screencast shows this behaviour: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0vslit5tejnmsm2/An%20accent%20is%20added%20when%20accented%20vowels%20follow%20a%20space.mp4?dl=0

To summarize, these are my conditions:

1. Firefox 69.0.1
2. Dropbox Paper
3. macOS 10.14.6
4. Greek input source

Tried the following:

1. New Firefox profile
2. New Firefox installation
3. Using Firefox with add-ons disabled
4. Private windows
5. New Mac user
6. New Mac installation (actually wiped my disk, reinstalled the OS, installed Firefox and tried it)

The issue still persists. I have been using Paper for quite some time and have not had this issue in the past. I assume it appeared in the last 3 months, perhaps after some Firefox update. I have also not observed the same behaviour in no other online form or text editor.